# Nagios Error : /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

Tags: centos, redhat

I am trying to install nagios-plugins-2.2.1 on redhat machine

when running this command:

```
Nagios /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

i am getting the error as

> no such file or directory

pls help

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsIrAsXzbx4

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the nagios binary is located in another location not in /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios

To find where it is run:

```
which nagios
```

If nagios was installed using the RHEL package manager so it will be usually in:

```
/usr/sbin/nagios
```

If it did not come back with result just type the first 3 letters "nag" then type the "Tab" key and it will complete it.

Once you find it then use it instead of /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios

Then make sure you get the right nagios.cfg file location by running the 2 following commands:

```
updatedb
locate nagios.cfg
```

If when you run updatedb you got "Command not found" error message then mlocate package is not installed and you can get the nagios.cfg location by running this command instead

```
find / -xdev -type f -name "nagios.cfg"
```

So by that you should have both "nagios binary" and "nagios.cfg file", you can then re-run the command with the right file paths

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "nagios.cfg" does not exist.

Try to create it and configuring it manually.

Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look at where your nagios.cfg file has been created, using

```
locate nagios.cfg
```

for instance, to make sure your file is in the right path and maybe call that newly displayed path instead.

```
/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v [path_of_nagios_cfg]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to omit the first "Nagios" from the command line as it is in Capital N which sure is supposed to come back with "no such file or directory" message

The command should only be like this:

```
/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

you will find nagios.cfg file in #/usr/local/nagios/etc
then run that command giving this path.